# Cron not running on webmin

Tags: cron, webmin

I have scheduled a cron on webmin as shown in the screenshot, but it is not being executed.

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: How do you know it is not being executed? What result do you expect from that `curl` call and what do you get instead?

Comment: and please add the things this changed on the server :)

Comment: @PerlDuck I know because "generateAllPrintReports"  is not being executed

Comment: @Rinzwind what things I should I add?

Comment: Change your job to `curl https://…/generateAllPrintReports 1>/tmp/curl.out 2>/tmp/curl.err` and see what is in these two files after the cronjob is supposed to run. I suspect the `curl` command isn't found because of the minimal environment cronjobs offer.